# Navigating from Location to Workorder

Tags: maximo

I need to :
1. Create a single page location application
2. Display all the asset present in the selected location in a table
3. Provide a button from which user can navigate to WOTRACK to view all the workorder(s) created on selected location and its asset(s).

I am facing difficulty in the 3rd one. I have tried Launch in Context and it is working fine except am not able to pass sql query like 'location={location} and assetnum in ({asset.assetnum})'. I need to filter workorders with particular location and all its assets.

I tried to save all the assets in the location to a Non-persistant attribute and passing the values of the attribute in the Launch in context url, Its working as expected but to do so I have written a script on 'Initialize value' which is causing performance issues.

script goes like this:

from psdi.server import MXServer;

from psdi.mbo import MboConstants;

if app == "LOCATION1" :

```
if mbo.getString("LOCATION") is not None:

    Locsite = mbo.getString("SITEID")

    desc = mbo.getString("DESCRIPTION")

    MaxuserSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("MAXUSER", mbo.getUserInfo())

    MaxuserSet.setWhere(" userid='"+user+"' ")

    MaxuserSet.reset()
    UserSite = MaxuserSet.getMbo(0).getString("DEFSITE")
    if Locsite == UserSite:
        AssetSet = mbo.getMboSet("ASSET")
        AssetSet.setFlag(MboConstants.DISCARDABLE, True);
        if not AssetSet.isEmpty():
            AssetList = ""
            AssetMbo = AssetSet.moveFirst()
            while AssetMbo is not None:
                AssetList = AssetList + str(AssetMbo.getString("ASSETNUM")) + "%2C"
                AssetMbo = AssetSet.moveNext()  
                mbo.setValue("non-persitant",str(AssetList),11L)
```

and in the LIC url i have given : 'http://xx.x.x.xx/maximo/ui/?event=loadapp&value=wotrack&tabid=List&additionalevent=useqbe&additionaleventvalue=location={LOCATION}|assetnum={non-persistant}'

Is there any other feasible solution to the requirement?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch In Context is better used for sending the user to an outside-of-Maximo application and passing along some data from inside-Maximo to provide context in that external app.

What you are doing sounds like a good place to use a workflow process with an Interaction node. The developer tells the Interaction node which app to take the user to and which Relationship to use to find the data the user should work with there.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a table control inside the table details (expanded table row) and show a list of the work orders there. From the WONUM in that table, you could have an app link to take them to WOTRACK, if they want more details about a particular work order. No customization (automation scripting) needed. No workflow needed. Nice and simple.